# CI/CD with Docker Compose on Google Cloud

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, docker-compose, google-container-os

I'm building a pipeline in Buddy where the application is build on command. New containers are build and pushed to DockerHub when it's time to deploy. I'm using Google's Container Optimized OS to run Docker Compose, [this way](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/docker-compose-on-container-optimized-os). But I can't find a way to automatically refresh and pull the latest container from DockerHub within the Contianer Optimized OS on a running instance.

Any idea how this can be achieved?

Comment: You mean you don't want that the OS use the container cache and always pull the latest image, correct?

Comment: Can you add some more details to your question - your setup specifically ?

Comment: Yes, I want to pull the latest image, whenever a new image is pushed